# Mostrar resultados nulos através do LEFT JOIN com Linq!

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, linq, visual-studio

Tenho uma consulta SQL:

```sql
SELECT A.Codplano, A.Secao, A.Setor,A.Subsetor,A.Contato, ISNULL(B.Subord,'NÃO
LANÇADA')AS Situacao 
FROM vwPLANODIN A LEFT JOIN LANCADA B
ON A.Codplano = B.Subord
and B.Data = '2014-06-10'
WHERE B.ID IS NULL and A.Sitio = 7341
```

que traduzida em Linq:

```cs
public static IEnumerable CobrancaCF(string data, int local)
    {
        WebDataDataContext dataClass = new WebDataDataContext();

        var dia = data;
        var sitio = local;

    var cob = from A in dataClass.vwPLANODINs
                  join B in dataClass.LANCADAs on new { A.Codplano, Data = data }
                  equals new { Codplano = B.Subord, Data = Convert.ToString(B.Data) }  into B_join
                  from B in B_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where
                       B.Data == null &&
                       A.Sitio == local
                  select new
                  {
                      A.Codplano,
                      A.Secao,
                      A.Setor,
                      A.Subsetor,
                      A.Contato,
                      Situacao = (B.Subord ?? "NÃO LANÇADA")
                  };    

IEnumerable cobranca = cob.AsEnumerable();

return cobranca;

}
```

Tenho que mostrar em um Gridview os dados não lançados, a consulta SQL retorna o que eu preciso, mas a consulta em Linq, retorna exatamente o contrário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou tentar responder com um exemplo:

*Veja imagem logo abaixo:*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela *People* está relacionada com *Phone*, sendo que sua relação não é obrigatório, ou seja, posso gravar `Phone` sem `People` (Phone.PeopleId pode conter valores `NULL`). Para que eu pegue todos os `Phone` independente de `People` tenho que usar `LEFT JOIN`.

***No Linq ([Linq To SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)) ficará assim:***

```
using (cboEntities db = new cboEntities())
{
    var result = db.Phone
            .GroupJoin(db.People, ph => ph.PeopleId, pe => pe.PeopleId, (ph, pe) => new { ph, pe })
            .SelectMany(s => s.pe.DefaultIfEmpty(), (ph, pe) => new
            {
               ph.ph.PhoneId,
               ph.ph.Ddd, 
               ph.ph.Number, 
               ph.ph.PeopleId, 
               ph.ph.People.FirstName                           
            });

    var resultToList = result.ToList();
}
```

**ou**

```
using (cboEntities db = new cboEntities())
{   
    var result = (from ph in db.Phone
               join pe in db.People on ph.PeopleId equals pe.PeopleId into peph
               from pe_ph in peph.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                  {
                      ph.PhoneId,
                      ph.Ddd, 
                      ph.Number, 
                      ph.PeopleId, 
                      ph.People.FirstName
                  });

    var resultToList = result.ToList();
}
```

***SQL Gerada:***

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PhoneId] AS [PhoneId], 
    [Extent1].[Ddd] AS [Ddd], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent1].[PeopleId] AS [PeopleId], 
    [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName]
    FROM  [dbo].[Phone] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PeopleId] = [Extent2].[PeopleId]
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o `PhoneId` **1** e **5**, não possui `People`, então, foi listado todos os registro da tabela `Phones` independente dos registros da tabela `People`

---

***Em relação ao seu problema, tente assim para ver qual o resultado.***

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Parse("10/06/2014");
String local = null;

var result = dataClass.vwPLANODINs
    .Where(x => 
        !dataClass.LANCADA.Where(la => la.Data == data).Select(g => g.Subord).Contains(x.Codplano) &&
        x.Sitio == local
        )
    .Select(s => new
    {
        s.Codplano,
        s.Secao,
        s.Setor,
        s.SubSetor,
        s.Contato,
        Situacao = "NÃO LANÇADA"
    });

var resultToList = result.ToList();
```

***Explicação:***
Quando penso em fazer um [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397687.aspx), primeiro em penso na [SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) que o [Entity Framework](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) deve gerar. Como você disse que deseja saber *"Equipes que não tiveram documento lançados em um determinada data"* e olhei tanto para sua [SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) que pensei que a mesma não ia fazer o que você bem queria. Resolvi então criar uma [SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) ficando assim:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Codplano] AS [Codplano], 
    [Extent1].[Secao] AS [Secao], 
    [Extent1].[Setor] AS [Setor], 
    [Extent1].[SubSetor] AS [SubSetor], 
    [Extent1].[Contato] AS [Contato]    
    FROM [dbo].[vwPLANODINs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[LANCADA] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Data] = "2014-06-10") AND ([Extent2].[Subord] = [Extent1].[Codplano]))
        ) AND [Extent1].[Sitio] = 7341)
```

Utilizando [NOT EXITS](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184297%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) e com os paramento a pesquisa ficou mais eficiente dessa forma, e com ela tranformei em [Linq To SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397926.aspx) como já postado logo acima.

*Dica: Sempre pense na [SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) para depois pensar no [Entity Framework](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework).*

***Obs:*** Tenho um exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21398/6026) de como testar as SQL geradas pelo Entity Framework.

Comment: @lll_JR_lll deve mesmo ta faltando alguma coisa, porque, o exemplo que eu te passei é funcional e correto, agora o seu eu não tenho idéia de suas tabelas e suas entidades, se puder colocar na sua pergunta o código das entidades seria mais tranquilo para que eu possa te ajudar!

Comment: postei o comentario anterior e ele ficou incompleto, segue: Não retornou nenhum valor. Acho que deixei de passar algumas informações que poderiam ajudar a entender o problema, segue: a view vwPLANODIN mostra todas as equipes cujo o cadastro está ativo e tabela LANCADA possui todos os documentos lançados (diarimente), eu preciso de uma consulta para me dizer quais as equipes não tiveram os documentos lançados em uma determinada data, a consulta escrita em SQL me retorna tranquilamente os dados, mas não consegui trazer a mesma informação no formato LINQ.

Comment: Fiz um edição aproximada para o que você precisa ...

Comment: Funcionou!!Se não for pedir muito, tem como me explicar como você chegou a solução. Antes de perguntar aqui eu passei uns três dias tentando.

Comment: @lll_JR_lll tentei explicar rapidamente, espero que te ajude!

Comment: Blz, vou estudar o NOT EXIST.