# Como saber qual SQL é gerado pelo ORM Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

Com a utilização do [**ORM**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional), e a prática empregada esquecemos que eles geram `SQLs` e retornar `Objetos` (vice-versa).

Como posso descobrir em tempo de execução a `SQL` gerada pelo [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) direto no [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/), para que possa debugar e ter um maior controle no que está sendo gerado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No que eu sei existem duas formas:

1) Cria a expressão `lambda expression` (`Linq`) com retorno [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e em outra variável `SQlExecutar` execute um [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Na variável com retorno [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tem a *SQL* gerada.

Nesse código apresentado, quando passar na instrução `SQL.ToList()` acima a variável `SQL` mostrará a `SELECT` gerada:

```cs
using (GenericsEntities db = new GenericsEntities())
{
    //Quando a variável "SQL" der um ToList() ela mostrado a "SELECT"
    IQueryable<Tipos> SQL = db.Tipos.AsQueryable();    
    IList<Tipos> SQLExecutar = SQL.ToList();        
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma forma de visualizar isso também é com *Breakpoint* com <kbd>F11</kbd> na janela *IntelliTrace* ver o *output*, observer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Na versão **EF** ***6+***, existe um [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) responsável por isso tendo uma saída de todas as informações de **conexão** e a **SQLs**. O [Database.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) resgata tais informações com a codificação logo abaixo. Eu crie um [function](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/) que tem um parâmetro do tipo [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que recebe os dados e imprime na tela do console.

```cs
using (GenericsEntities db = new GenericsEntities())
{
    db.Database.Log = StrRestult => fs(StrRestult); 
    IQueryable<Tipos> SQL = db.Tipos.AsQueryable();
    IList<Tipos> SQLExecutar = SQL.ToList();
}
//função que irá imprimir na tela (console) tudo o que 
//aconteceu nas instruções de conexão e SQLs geradas
private static void fs(string StrRestult)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(StrRestult);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É de grande utilidade como forma de debugar e visualizar como ele trabalha internamente.

A segunda opção é a mais eficaz, porque, consigo também visualizar `Insert`, `Delete`, `Update` e `Select` de forma bem clara.