# Consulta bem lenta para exportar em excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, entity-framework, linq

Criei um método para exportar algumas colunas para xls e está bem lento o processo, demora em torno de quase um minuto para fazer todo processo.

```
    public void Download(string datainicio, string datafinal, int? searchContrato, string searchCliente, string tipo, string status)
    {
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(datainicio);
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(datafinal);

        var tbl_caminhos = db.tbl_caminho_backup.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ativo == true && x.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.ativo == true).ToList();
        var tbl_logs = db.vw_logs_backuponline.AsNoTracking().Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.data_inicio) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt1) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.data_inicio) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt2)).ToList();

        //List<vw_logs_backuponline> tbl_logs = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tipo))
        {
            tbl_caminhos = tbl_caminhos.Where(x => x.tipo == tipo).ToList();

            tbl_logs = tbl_logs.Where(s => s.log_tipo == tipo).ToList();
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCliente))
        {
            tbl_caminhos = tbl_caminhos.Where(x => x.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.nome_razao.ToLower().Contains(searchCliente.ToLower())).ToList();
            tbl_logs = tbl_logs.Where(s => s.nome_razao.ToLower().Contains(searchCliente.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        if (searchContrato != null)
        {
            tbl_caminhos = tbl_caminhos.Where(x => x.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.contrato == searchContrato).ToList();

            tbl_logs = tbl_logs.Where(s => s.contrato == searchContrato).ToList();
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && status == "0")
        {
            tbl_caminhos = tbl_caminhos.Where(x => !tbl_logs.Select(l => l.id_caminho_backup).Contains(x.id_caminho_backup)).ToList();

            tbl_logs = tbl_logs.Where(s => s.data_fim != null).ToList();
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && status == "1")
        {
            tbl_caminhos = null;
            tbl_logs = tbl_logs.Where(s => s.data_fim != null).ToList();
        }

        if (tbl_caminhos != null)
        {
            for (DateTime dtRef = dt1; dtRef <= dt2; dtRef = dtRef.AddDays(1))
            {
                //aqui pego todos os caminhos cadastrados para os clientes
                foreach (var caminhos in tbl_caminhos)
                {
                    //verifico se existe um log para o caminho, se tiver eu sei que foi realizado o backup
                    if (tbl_logs.Where(x => x.id_caminho_backup == caminhos.id_caminho_backup && (x.data_inicio >= dtRef && x.data_inicio <= dtRef)).Count() <= 0)
                    {
                        //se entrou aqui é pq não existe um log para o caminho, então crio uma linha de falha do backup
                        vw_logs_backuponline log = new vw_logs_backuponline();
                        log.contrato = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.contrato;
                        log.nome_razao = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.nome_razao;
                        log.cidade = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.cidade;
                        log.log_tipo = caminhos.tipo;
                        log.data_inicio = dtRef;
                        log.hora_inicio = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.hora_backup;
                        log.bucket = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.bucket;
                        log.hora_backup = caminhos.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.hora_backup;
                        log.msg_operacao = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-alert' aria-hidden='true'></span>";
                        log.caminho_ativo = true;

                        tbl_logs.Add(log);
                    }
                }
            }
            //aqui removo os com sucesso quando a busca é apenas os com falhas
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && status == "0")
            {
                tbl_logs.RemoveAll(x => x.data_fim != null);
            }

        }
        var logs = tbl_logs.Select(x => new LogsBackup() { Contrato = x.contrato, Modalidade = x.log_tipo, Cidade = x.cidade, UF = x.uf, Nome_Razao = x.nome_razao, Dias_Backup = (x.data_inicio - x.data_fim).ToString().FirstOrDefault().ToString() }).AsQueryable().ToList();

        try
        {
            GridView gridView = new GridView();

            gridView.DataSource = logs;
            gridView.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + datafinal + "VerusBackup.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";

            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                {

                    gridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
                    Response.Output.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Script na View:

```
  $("#btnExportar").click(function (e) {
    var datainicio = $('#datainicio').val();
    var datafinal = $('#datafinal').val();
    var searchContrato = $('#searchContrato').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
    var status = $('#status').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "@Url.Action("Download", "logsbackuponline")",
        data: { datainicio: datainicio, datafinal: datafinal, searchContrato: searchContrato, tipo: tipo, status: status },
        async: true,
        success: function (Result) {
            window.location = '/logsbackuponline/Download?datainicio=' + datainicio + '&datafinal=' + datafinal + '&searchContrato=' + searchContrato + '&tipo=' + tipo + '&status=' + status;
        }
    })        
});
```

Comment: o que você já analisou? já usou o *diagnostic tools* pra identificar onde está a lentidão?

Comment: Nem cheguei a usar a tool, está perceptível a lentidão ao clicar no botão para exportar.

Comment: Problemas de performance raramente andam sozinhos. Para começar, acredito que seria interessante você primeiro identificar se o problema está na requisição, no processamento do backend (e se esse for o caso qual bloco é o que está causando a demora e precisa ser otimizado) ou no upload do arquivo gerado. De cara eu to vendo um monte de `ToList` dispensável no código e eu realmente não sei o que você pretende com esse trecho `(x.data_inicio - x.data_fim).ToString().FirstOrDefault().ToString()`.

Comment: Adriano, *"ao clicar no botão"* me faz pensar numa caixa preta. Você clica e está lento é um comentário de usuário isso, precisa olhar o código e inspecionar pra ver onde está lento.. no retorno do banco? no `foreach`, gerando o arquivo, no download mesmo? se você usar o *diagnostic tools* por exemplo, vai ver onde está mais lento, dai pode analisar exatamente esse ponto, senão fica difícil te ajudar

Comment: @RicardoPontual é na consulta ao DB, quando fiz está query a resposta foi momentânea, porém quando mudei para o exemplo acima, a resposta demora 00:00:56 segundos.

                var tbl_logs = db.vw_logs_backuponline.Select(x => { x.nome_razao, x.cidade, x.uf, x.log_tipo})AsNoTracking().Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.data_inicio) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt1) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.data_inicio) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt2));

Comment: muito bom Adriano, agora seria legal ver a query gerada pra analisar o que pode estar causando lentidão, até analisar o plano de execução. Você consegue capturar a query? Se não souber, tem essa pergunta que explica bem como fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21398/como-saber-qual-sql-%C3%A9-gerado-pelo-orm-entity-framework

Comment: Então, ficou assim o código abaixo no link, a lentidão ocorre bem na 39, e o select é esse: https://pastebin.com/FYHZ8Zjf 

Código atual: https://pastebin.com/Ud6wzLFL

Comment: *A lentidão ocorre bem na linha 39 (onde os dados retornam de uma view), e o select é esse: https://pastebin.com/FYHZ8Zjf 

Código atual: https://pastebin.com/Ud6wzLFL

Answer (score 3):

Logo de início você pode tirar todos esses `ToList()` e executar a query só no final. Exemplo:

```
var tbl_caminhos = db.tbl_caminho_backup.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ativo && x.tbl_cliente_verusbackuponline.ativo);


if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tipo))
{
    tbl_caminhos = tbl_caminhos.Where(x => x.tipo == tipo);
}


var caminhos = tbl_caminhos.ToList();
```

Assim a query é executada apenas uma vez, ao final quando estiver aplicada todos os filtros.

Depois disso, podemos analisar quantidade de registros, ou outros fatores que podem estar causando a lentidão

> ps. não precisa de comparar um campo bool com true, `ativo == true`, `ativo` já irá retornar `true` ou `false`